Cannot place latex table at bottom of page when using emulateapj document class
I'm at my wits end here. I am using the emulateapj document class, which uses two columns of text. I have a table that is too wide for one column, no biggie I thought I'd just use the \begin{table*} and get on with my day. Problem is as soon as I use the * I have no control over the placement of the table. When I put the table in one column I can use the normal [h] command and it renders as you'd expect, it's only an issue when I try to make it span both columns. below I've tried to recreate the problem with some anonymity lol, but it uses the exact same preamble and when I compile it gives me the same issue, all thats changed are the content of the table.
\documentclass[apj,iop]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor=Blue4,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}


\begin{document}

\title{table example}
\author{john doe}
\affil{best university ever}
%\date{July 2024}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus nunc vel luctus ultrices. Nam quam ante, pretium in sagittis vitae, viverra ut nibh. Suspendisse aliquet bibendum risus nec efficitur. Mauris felis risus, condimentum maximus tincidunt id, tincidunt vitae lacus. Vivamus at risus auctor, hendrerit nunc at, ultrices nibh. Nullam venenatis nibh vel mattis blandit. Phasellus sagittis, velit ac porta fringilla, eros magna bibendum lectus, non vulputate libero turpis quis neque. Nam hendrerit dui mauris  \\
\end{abstract}

 

\keywords{really good science}

\section{Introduction}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus nunc vel luctus ultrices. Nam quam ante, pretium in sagittis vitae, viverra ut nibh. Suspendisse aliquet bibendum risus nec efficitur. Mauris felis risus, condimentum maximus tincidunt id, tincidunt vitae lacus. Vivamus at risus auctor, hendrerit nunc at, ultrices nibh. Nullam venenatis nibh vel mattis blandit. Phasellus sagittis, velit ac porta fringilla, eros magna bibendum lectus, non vulputate libero turpis quis neque. Nam hendrerit dui mauris.

Maecenas cursus dui in ligula ultricies commodo quis nec urna. Aenean mollis, elit nec viverra rutrum, tortor augue fermentum velit, non ultrices enim augue sed orci. Aenean sollicitudin, ipsum quis commodo sollicitudin, lacus nulla eleifend massa, nec semper ex turpis in eros. Praesent posuere tempus augue, vel porttitor augue rutrum sed. Etiam ut justo pellentesque, faucibus nisl ac, porttitor dui. Vestibulum volutpat euismod ullamcorper. Integer ac lectus nisi. Donec id lorem a augue ornare pharetra. Nulla dictum lorem sit amet diam suscipit, ut ornare dolor vestibulum.

Sed consequat velit quis ultricies fringilla. Donec ultricies non neque nec iaculis. Suspendisse at pellentesque ipsum. Mauris pharetra nibh condimentum lacinia laoreet. Nunc ipsum magna, porttitor in sollicitudin pellentesque, feugiat non orci. Curabitur vel magna vitae libero mattis lobortis. Integer cursus lacinia odio non scelerisque. Etiam congue aliquam turpis, ut malesuada urna pharetra eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus lorem non neque laoreet fermentum. In eleifend urna odio, sit amet scelerisque massa cursus ut.

Nulla ut felis a ipsum interdum tempus in vel libero. Sed dolor ex, sagittis sed sodales nec, laoreet eu nunc. Nunc dictum eros ante, eget molestie libero efficitur sed. In vel sapien tellus. Praesent tincidunt lacus a diam posuere tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras tristique faucibus magna, porttitor tincidunt urna iaculis quis. Sed volutpat nisi quis velit elementum, sed maximus mauris imperdiet. Curabitur convallis est dictum nunc euismod porttitor. Integer cursus ex id laoreet aliquet. Maecenas ut diam aliquet, congue diam et, scelerisque felis. Vivamus ac mi feugiat, mollis massa vitae, bibendum purus. Nam pharetra tincidunt tempus. Aenean malesuada orci ac aliquam volutpat. Nunc posuere suscipit nunc, et ullamcorper lacus luctus et. Quisque quis lobortis nunc.

Nunc mi lacus, laoreet non massa vitae, ornare facilisis neque. Vestibulum sagittis semper nibh non ornare. Nulla vitae elementum eros. Curabitur volutpat odio at consequat suscipit. Sed dapibus eros tempus, sagittis orci ut, laoreet leo. Curabitur placerat tempor mauris in laoreet. Curabitur lacinia tristique ipsum accumsan malesuada. Etiam vel tellus hendrerit, feugiat dolor non, accumsan sem. In facilisis id velit dictum viverra. Sed mollis laoreet turpis quis tincidunt. Ut ut ante posuere, pulvinar risus pharetra, scelerisque lectus. Nullam mi nunc, interdum ut consequat in, rutrum vitae massa. Morbi accumsan urna nibh, in vehicula neque efficitur eget. Cras at sapien tortor. Pellentesque a egestas ligula. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus nunc vel luctus ultrices. Nam quam ante, pretium in sagittis vitae, viverra ut nibh. Suspendisse aliquet bibendum risus nec efficitur. Mauris felis risus, condimentum maximus tincidunt id, tincidunt vitae lacus. Vivamus at risus auctor, hendrerit nunc at, ultrices nibh. Nullam venenatis nibh vel mattis blandit. Phasellus sagittis, velit ac porta fringilla, eros magna bibendum lectus, non vulputate libero turpis quis neque. Nam hendrerit dui mauris.

Maecenas cursus dui in ligula ultricies commodo quis nec urna. Aenean mollis, elit nec viverra rutrum, tortor augue fermentum velit, non ultrices enim augue sed orci. Aenean sollicitudin, ipsum quis commodo sollicitudin, lacus nulla eleifend massa, nec semper ex turpis in eros. Praesent posuere tempus augue, vel porttitor augue rutrum sed. Etiam ut justo pellentesque, faucibus nisl ac, porttitor dui. Vestibulum volutpat euismod ullamcorper. Integer ac lectus nisi. Donec id lorem a augue ornare pharetra. Nulla dictum lorem sit amet diam suscipit, ut ornare dolor vestibulum.

Sed consequat velit quis ultricies fringilla. Donec ultricies non neque nec iaculis. Suspendisse at pellentesque ipsum. Mauris pharetra nibh condimentum lacinia laoreet. Nunc ipsum magna, porttitor in sollicitudin pellentesque, feugiat non orci. Curabitur vel magna vitae libero mattis lobortis. Integer cursus lacinia odio non scelerisque. Etiam congue aliquam turpis, ut malesuada urna pharetra eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus lorem non neque laoreet fermentum. In eleifend urna odio, sit amet scelerisque massa cursus ut.


\section{methadology}

\begin{table*}[b]
\large
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt} % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
x & y  & z & a & b & c \\ \hline
1         & 7           & 8                   & 9          & 10         & 11           \\
2         & 12            & 13                  & 14          & 15            & 16           \\
3         & 17             & 18                   & 19          & 20             & 21           \\
4         & 22             & 23                  & 24          & 25             & 26         \\
5      & 27            & 28                 & 29          & 30            & 31        \\
6      & 32             & 33                 & 34          & 35            & 36        
\end{tabular}
\caption{the best table you've ever seen}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus nunc vel luctus ultrices. Nam quam ante, pretium in sagittis vitae, viverra ut nibh. Suspendisse aliquet bibendum risus nec efficitur. Mauris felis risus, condimentum maximus tincidunt id, tincidunt vitae lacus. Vivamus at risus auctor, hendrerit nunc at, ultrices nibh. Nullam venenatis nibh vel mattis blandit. Phasellus sagittis, velit ac porta fringilla, eros magna bibendum lectus, non vulputate libero turpis quis neque. Nam hendrerit dui mauris.

Maecenas cursus dui in ligula ultricies commodo quis nec urna. Aenean mollis, elit nec viverra rutrum, tortor augue fermentum velit, non ultrices enim augue sed orci. Aenean sollicitudin, ipsum quis commodo sollicitudin, lacus nulla eleifend massa, nec semper ex turpis in eros. Praesent posuere tempus augue, vel porttitor augue rutrum sed. Etiam ut justo pellentesque, faucibus nisl ac, porttitor dui. Vestibulum volutpat euismod ullamcorper. Integer ac lectus nisi. Donec id lorem a augue ornare pharetra. Nulla dictum lorem sit amet diam suscipit, ut ornare dolor vestibulum.

Sed consequat velit quis ultricies fringilla. Donec ultricies non neque nec iaculis. Suspendisse at pellentesque ipsum. Mauris pharetra nibh condimentum lacinia laoreet. Nunc ipsum magna, porttitor in sollicitudin pellentesque, feugiat non orci. Curabitur vel magna vitae libero mattis lobortis. Integer cursus lacinia odio non scelerisque. Etiam congue aliquam turpis, ut malesuada urna pharetra eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus lorem non neque laoreet fermentum. In eleifend urna odio, sit amet scelerisque massa cursus ut.

Nulla ut felis a ipsum interdum tempus in vel libero. Sed dolor ex, sagittis sed sodales nec, laoreet eu nunc. Nunc dictum eros ante, eget molestie libero efficitur sed. In vel sapien tellus. Praesent tincidunt lacus a diam posuere tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras tristique faucibus magna, porttitor tincidunt urna iaculis quis. Sed volutpat nisi quis velit elementum, sed maximus mauris imperdiet. Curabitur convallis est dictum nunc euismod porttitor. Integer cursus ex id laoreet aliquet. Maecenas ut diam aliquet, congue diam et, scelerisque felis. Vivamus ac mi feugiat, mollis massa vitae, bibendum purus. Nam pharetra tincidunt tempus. Aenean malesuada orci ac aliquam volutpat. Nunc posuere suscipit nunc, et ullamcorper lacus luctus et. Quisque quis lobortis nunc.

Nunc mi lacus, laoreet non massa vitae, ornare facilisis neque. Vestibulum sagittis semper nibh non ornare. Nulla vitae elementum eros. Curabitur volutpat odio at consequat suscipit. Sed dapibus eros tempus, sagittis orci ut, laoreet leo. Curabitur placerat tempor mauris in laoreet. Curabitur lacinia tristique ipsum accumsan malesuada. Etiam vel tellus hendrerit, feugiat dolor non, accumsan sem. In facilisis id velit dictum viverra. Sed mollis laoreet turpis quis tincidunt. Ut ut ante posuere, pulvinar risus pharetra, scelerisque lectus. Nullam mi nunc, interdum ut consequat in, rutrum vitae massa. Morbi accumsan urna nibh, in vehicula neque efficitur eget. Cras at sapien tortor. Pellentesque a egestas ligula. 
\end{document}

Apologies for the length of the text, but I wanted to give an idea of where exactly I want the table to sit. It should be at the bottom of the second page with any excess text moved to the next page but instead it renders either in the top or middle of the third page. If I add in another figure it will show up below it on the third page, so it's not forcing everything off of whatever page it's on, it just refuses to play nice with the text for some reason.
I have tried the classic [h] and [h!] and [H] commands from the relevant packages, no change.
I also tried [b], [b!], [!b}, [bp], [htb], [htpb], and just to see if it changed anything I tried the [t], [t!], and [!t] commands as well, it seems independent of any of these. It will always either render at the top of the third page or in the middle of the third page.
I tried \clearpage before and after the table. All it does is shunt the text down to page 4, leaving the table all by itself on page 3 still.
I tried changing the bottom fraction via the \setcounter{bottomnumber}{1} and \renewcommand\bottomefraction{0.5} and tried a range of numbers from {0.3} to {0.9}. No change.
I have tried loading the dblfloatfix and stfloats packages. No change.
I have tried placing it elsewhere in the document, which finally had some effect but still didn't get me what I wanted. the only thing that has had a noticeable effect on the table is shrinking it considerably (to the point that its almost unreadable), and moving it way way earlier in the document. Even then, I can only get it to be on a page with text if I lock it to the top of the page with [t]. If I try [b] in this case, its back to the middle of the next page all by itself. If I make the table wide enough to be legible, even the [t] command doesn't work and I'm left, again, with a table floating by itself in the middle of the page.
I am using overleaf but I did try downloading the zip file and rendering things in my own offline tex compiler. I have yet to repeat all the troubleshooting I did in overleaf but from what I've tried the issue still seems to persist.
I'd really prefer to have the table at the bottom of the page, it is awkward and out of place at the top, and it definitely can't be floating alone in the middle of a page. And even when I can get it to the top of the page, its only when its too tiny to be of any use. Is there any way around this? I cannot use an appendix for this document, and its hard to believe theres no way to put a table at the bottom of a page, any thoughts?

You could try this trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/36296

... or not add so much space between the table columns so your table will comfortable fit in a single text column
